# UITableViewCell icons in the left margin/gutter

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I display icons to the left of the `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView`?

The Mail app does this, and I'm wondering if this is a native feature that comes with iOS, or one that need a custom implementation.

Thanks!

[image: iOS 8 Mail App]

Comment: You create a custom cell and add a UIImageView

Comment: there is no native feature comes with iOS for this kind of implementation but you can implement it by creating the custom cell and design it as you want.

Comment: That image is not "left of the cell", it's part of the cell. With a custom cell, you can put your content where you want, as well as inset the separator so it looks like the cell doesn't go all the way to the left edge of the screen

Comment: That's it @rdelmar, a *custom separator inset* is the key to making it look like the icons are outside of the main cell area. Unfortunately I can't **accept** a comment as an answer :)

Comment: @RichaSharma Yes I did.

Comment: @rdelmar, if you make that an *answer*, I can then accept it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit should really go to @rdelmar, but as he gave the solution in in a comment rather than an answer, I'm posting this for other people:

> That image is not "left of the cell", it's part of the cell. With a
>   custom cell, you can put your content where you want, as well as inset
>   the separator so it looks like the cell doesn't go all the way to the
>   left edge of the screen

Answer (score 1):

If you have Custom `UITableViewCell` then you can implement `layoutSubviews` as follows:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(5, 5, 15, 15);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 15, 15);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

I have used this one. It works. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `UITableViewCell` with a class of your own.

In this new class of yours you can have your own layout and complete control of what you want the cell to look like. On interface builder for this cell you can have the image and just add a method to display/hide such image.

When implementing your UITableView you will need to specify your cell identifier for your new class so it loads the right nib.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCellClass";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```